# Extracting HTML from Java after execution of Scripts

Tags: java, html

I have one HTML file, which consist of a UI defenition and an XML file with some data, that will be rendered in this UI using script parsing. This is achieved by browser and it's rendering perfectly. Now my question is about any way to do this rendering without a browser, and extract the resulting HTML, with all data values in places, so that I can make a HTML file seperately, that I need for a PDF creation.

Can I do this task from Java? is there any option available?

*edit:*

I found one simulation library called HtmlUnit from Sourceforge. That renders the HTML properly, and is executing few scripts. The problem is their JavaScript engine is not supporting DOMParser or any XML parsing methods. Any one know a solution to this?

Comment: *"i need for a PDF creation."*  I always shudder when I hear that.  PDF is good for printing and almost nothing else, but a scrollable web page often looks like dog defecation when converted to PDF.

Comment: Why i said PDF is, i needed it for the FAX. My page may not be exceeding 1 page. However if HTML content could be got, its enough

Comment: Here, we are using an Internet FAXing feature. So for this we need the files to be in ether PDF or plain html. The problem is only with populating the html with xml data, and retrieve the resulting source.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [XSLT](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/samples.html) to do this ?

Comment: XSLT was considered. But the pages are not something generic. This pages may be created by different people as they like. For. eg a sales order of one company differs from other. Here each company will generate their own pages. So we cant add an annotation for some variable structure of data.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Flying Saucer](http://xhtmlrenderer.java.net/) which is using [iText underneath](http://itextpdf.com/) you can convert the html with css into a PDF.

The bit I don't understand is how the HTML and XML get displayed in a browser. Is there a lot of javascript that pulls the xml apart and injects into into the HTML? Is there some library that is doing some template processing?

-edit-

I was afraid that you were using javascript to populate the page.
I am just offering suggestions because I'm really not sure how to procede.

[Cobra](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp) looks like it is a library that can handle html and javascript. It seems like it is only supporting html4 at the moment and I don't know if you can supply all of the input and have it produce an output stream that you could then provide to Flying Saucer.

You may have to take a step back and create a specific page that gets populated by the xml data for this purpose.

Comment: XML is injected using javascript and DOMParsing methods only. But this function will be called by browser on load/actions. But how we can acheive it in backend?

Comment: Flying Saucer is not supporting Scripting..:(

Comment: Try using SWT without opening the shell. browser.evaluate("return doc.getElementsBYTagName('html')[0].innerHTML"); call will return the html content.